# firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.storage is not a function , firbase.storge() method not work also try firebaseApp.storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

(`npm firebase ^9.6.10`)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export {
  auth,
  provider,
  storage
};
export default db;
```

Answer (score 3):

You must import Firebase Storage SDK as well just like Firestore and other Firebase services:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

// Add Firebase storage
import 'firebase/compat/storage';
```

Comment: i do same but it not working bro

Comment: @NavinSolanki have you tried restarting the React dev server?

Comment: dev server means npm start you talking

Comment: @NavinSolanki yes.. if that still doesn't work.. can you update your question with latest code that you havae?

Comment: sorry bro now it working  i forgot this library that you mention // Add Firebase storage
import 'firebase/compat/storage';

Comment: <-now it working but i get new error ->
react_devtools_backend.js:3973 [2022-04-13T16:12:53.397Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.10): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project disneyplus-clone-a33d5.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: @NavinSolanki that error is related with Firestore and security rules. I'd recommend posting that as a new question with code of your Firestore queries, security rules and any screenshot of the errors for better visibility.